# Tag confusion now that there are two “magic keyboards”

Tags: discussion, tags

We’ve not had a [magic-keyboard](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-keyboard) tag on the main site until the iPad version of that gear was released recently. I created that tag, but wanted to see if there was consensus how to use the main [keyboard](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/keyboard) tag vs the iPad one.

I could see three scenarios:

- send all usages to [keyboard](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/keyboard) and maybe have synonyms, maybe just merge them down.
- keep [keyboard](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/keyboard) for the Magic Keyboard that is bluetooth and lightning/USB connected and keep [magic-keyboard](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-keyboard) for the one that physically connects to iPad Pro with three electrical contacts and also has backlight and trackpad integrated in with the keyboard.
- make specific tags like [magic-keyboard-bluetooth](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-keyboard-bluetooth) and [magic-keyboard-ipad](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-keyboard-ipad) or something so that we can hopefully manage when someone chooses the wrong tag and make tag wiki that provide guidance.

If you feel strongly about one of these options being best, please choose your warrior and write a small defense on why it’s right. If no one has any opinion, we can let things ride until there’s a need to act.

No matter what way we go - we should edit the wiki tag summary / usage appropriately once there is consensus on a direction to take.

Comment: Haven't given this much thought, but initially I like the idea of using 'iPad' as part of the tag name for these keyboards, so `magic-keyboard-ipad` would be my preference. As to whether we need to act now, or wait and see, happy to go with the flow.

Comment: Do you think we should just rename it now for clarity - renaming an existing tag is super easy to reverse, @Monomeeth

Comment: Yep, let's do it! :)

Answer (score 1):

For now - I will make an edit to change [magic-keyboard](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-keyboard) to be [magic-keyboard-ipad](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-keyboard-ipad) so it’s very clear which hardware should be tagged.